# jQuery Webcam plug-in only save 1 image

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

in my asp.net mvc 5 EF6 project i am using a jquery plug-in for webcam image capture.

code is here

```
<script src="~/Scripts/webcam.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript">

Webcam.set({
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    dest_width: 400,
    dest_height: 400,
    image_format: 'jpeg',
    jpeg_quality: 90,
    force_flash: false,
    flip_horiz: true,
    fps: 45
});
    Webcam.attach( '#webcam' );

    function take_snapshot() {
        Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
            document.getElementById('my_result').innerHTML = '<img src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
        } );
    }
```

it is working fine, capture is fine.

but it only capture **1 image at a time.**

i want when i click on **"Take Snapshot"** button, it capture the next image and display a serious of images.

how it is possible

Thanks

Comment: instead of *overwriting* the content of `my_result`, you need to **append** new elements to it.

Comment: agreed......but how?